# .Net 4/Mvc Runtime Cache strangeness

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, caching, .net-4.0

**Update: I have dropped the cache system in favor of a database solution - pitty.**

I have a backend MVC controller where i need data caching. I use *MemoryCache.Default* to store key/value pairs, nothing big. Nevermind policies and expire times, i'f got that. The thing that mystifys me is why my cache gets cleaned out after I'f accessed a key (retrived the value) the first time. If i don't access the cached item, eventually the item will expire and my remove handler is called - it's all good. But when i retrive the item the first time, my remove handler is called after a short while. The *ChacheEntryRemovedReason* is set to:

```
CacheSpecificEviction // A cache entry was evicted for as reason that is defined by a particular cache implementation.
```

I can't find any explanation to what this means.
The mystifying thing here is that when i inspect the cache object when debugging in the handler (and on succeeding controller calls), the cache enum is empty. If I "set" (add) a new CacheItem to the cache, I can yet again access the key once, and history repeats.
The behavior is like a one-off caching mechanism which i totally don't need.
Any help or comments would be much appreciated!

Some simplified code just for the fun of it:

```
   private static ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default; 

   internal void insertInCache(string key, int value) {
        CacheItemPolicy policy= new CacheItemPolicy() {
            AbsoluteExpiration = ObjectCache.InfiniteAbsoluteExpiration,
            Priority = CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable,
            SlidingExpiration =  TimeSpan.FromMinutes(ITEM_EXPIRE_TIME),
            RemovedCallback = new CacheEntryRemovedCallback(RemovedHandler)
        };
        cache.Set(key, value, policy);
    }

    static void RemovedHandler(CacheEntryRemovedArguments args) {
        if(args.RemovedReason == CacheEntryRemovedReason.Expired) {
            //do something - or i actually want it to disappear when expired
        } else {
            cache.Set(args.CacheItem, somepolicy);//reinsert to keep in cache
        }
    }

    //Apparently this triggers some cache mong mode
    internal void getSome(string key){
        int thisIsWhatIWanted = (int)cache.GetCacheItem(key).Value;
    }
```

This is just example code so please don't nag me about my skillz.
My own best guess is that it may have to do with the cache not being setup properly, MVC witchery or the fact I'm running my application on a debug IIS (visual studido)